# Multiple displays

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am currently using Ubuntu 13.4, And I sometimes use two screen to make things easier sometimes; but there is an annoying problem.

[image]

whenever I try to change the resolution at a different level on any screen, The orientation locks itself to clockwise and their is no way to return it back to normal unless I exit. I actually allowed it once to keep the changes and it got stuck until I figured out how to stop that nonsense with the orientation. so now I cant upgrade the resolution and stay stuck on the 1000X800 resolution on both screens. how do I change it normally? I used to be able to do that without that annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar an 9-year-old Inspiron, and received an error message saying like the dimensions of my two screens exceeded a 2048 x 2048 box.

On the screen shown in your post, I moved the external monitor above the laptop (so red and the green boxes were vertically stacked, instead of side-by-side).  It no longer forces the external monitor to be clockwise or counter-clockwise.  The normal orientation is now an option.